# Net::SSH::Shell::Process $DONTEVERUSETHIS

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, ssh

When using Net::SSH to run commands on a remote connection, it adds the following script to the end of each and every command:

`DONTEVERUSETHIS=$?; echo #{manager.separator} $DONTEVERUSETHIS; echo \"exit $DONTEVERUSETHIS\"|sh`

the output produced looks like:

> DONTEVERUSETHIS=$?; echo 10e75e2821012645fa3a3cc08ec5de527a392af68db4c3cac63dac22d4de2a8708fcc176190817fe $DONTEVERUSETHIS; echo "exit $DONTEVERUSETHIS"|sh

Here's a link to the source code [Net::SSH::Shell::Process](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/net-ssh-shell-0.2.0/Net/SSH/Shell/Process.html) and look at the 'run' method

Can anyone explain why this is always added?

It doesn't appear in the console output but plays hell with parsing ~/.bash_history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: It's the machine readable equivalent of a colored shell prompt. It's there to tell the library when the issued command has finished, and whether it was successful.

---

When running a command with `Net::SSH` (not `::Shell`), here's what happens:

1. Connection is established
2. Command is sent
3. Output is received
4. The command exits, `sshd` returns the exit code and ends the connection.

This means that it's easy to:

- Get the output: just read until sshd closes the connection.
- Get the exit code. `sshd` returns it.

However, it means that each command is run in a separate session, so `cd /tmp` followed by `pwd` will return `/home/youruser` because these are two different sessions, so the former doesn't affect the latter.

---

The purpose of `Net::SSH::Shell` is instead to run multiple, individual commands in the same shell session:

1. Connection is established.
2. Commands are sent as a single, infinite, concatenated stream
3. Output is received as a single, infinite, concatenated stream

This leaves two open questions:

- How do you know whether the command has finished or whether it's still processing?
- How do you get the exit code now that `sshd` doesn't return it?

The way `Net::SSH::Shell` solves this is by modifying the command in the way you saw, to make it print a unique ID and exit code when done:

- To get the command's output, read until a line with the unique ID is printed.
- To get the exit code, read it from the same line.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look into the source repository reveals [this commit](https://github.com/mitchellh/net-ssh-shell/commit/38855d1):

> keep the exitcode 1 available for the next command

In effect, this allows you to inspect the value of `$?` (i.e. the *exitcode* of the *previous* command)  in the *next* command.